# Can I interpret 15x coverage area as a part of one strand is missing?

Tags: wgs, indel, igv, chromosomes

This is a BAM file from a 30x coverage Nebula Genomics test opened with IGV.

I found an area (1:30169255-30169600) where the coverage is less than 15x. Can I interpret it as a part of one strand of Chromosome 1 is missing?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE:

Seeing a different question where similar vocabulary is used: it would not be one *strand* that would be lost. single stranded DNA is not very happy in the nucleus, and would either lead to something seriously bad or be gap-filled to make it dsDNA again.

It would instead be that one of two chromosomes has a deletion at that position, which would be a classic CNV.

### ORIGINAL ANSWER:

No.

There are a variety of copy number variant (CNV) calling tools that put a lot of effort into statistically robust ways of asking this question, all of which are a lot more complex than just looking at raw coverage. [I'd recommend looking more into them](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-93878-2).

In terms of explanations for lower coverage in some regions that aren't CNVs: sequenceability of DNA is not even, replication of DNA is not even, mappability of reads is not even, etc. You need to reject those hypotheses before you go to variants.